# What could be causing this cordova error?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

We developed a quite simple application with ionic + cordova, testing only on an iOS device. We always wanted for the application to be cross-platform, but testing on an Android device didn't worked as expected.

In the app we have a feature that requires a picture to be taken. But apparently the picture does not even get saved on the device. It errors with `Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected String, but got Null.`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
      var options = {
        destinationType: $window.Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        targetWidth: 1500,
      };

      $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(picture) {
        this.storePicture(picture);
      }.bind(this));
```

The error appears to happen in the `getPicture()` call. As you can see, I'm using Angular with ng-cordova.

I tried searching, but all answers I found didn't help me. Does anyone have an idea on how we can solve this problem?

Comment: You should post your error relating code

Comment: Thanks for the tip, included.

Comment: No, everything in this code is OK. The callback is not executed, though.

Comment: Why are you appending `$window` in front of `Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI`? I cannot find any example in the cordova-plugin-camera examples...

Comment: I'm using Angular with ng-cordova.

Comment: Example in ngcordova suggests to use Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI with no prefix, did you try and inspect what kind of options are passed to getPicture? It might be that destinationType is undefined. If this is not the case - it might be bug in plugin. Either-way, does i work correctly on iOS?

Comment: It does work correctly in iOS devices, and the `options` object does not have any undefined values. The prefix does not make a difference, the `$window` object points to the browser's `window` object. I do this so I can mock this in unit tests.

Comment: @DenisLins Did you manage to resolve it? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, no. Android support is not needed for us at this stage and so we decided to leave this as it is for now.

Comment: @AvijitGupta did u solve this issue cos im having it too now

Comment: @KingsleySimon Unfortunately no :(